# Best Reference for creating web socket server in spring 4

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to build a web socket server for `chatting application`. I made a sample java application for connecting server to client with web sockets. But i don't know how to do same in Spring framework.

Also, It would be a great help if you could also tell me how to manage multiple `web-socket sessions` on server end.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WebSocketConnector {

    private static Set<Session> allSessions;

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException,     InterruptedException {

        // Print the client message for testing purposes
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        allSessions = session.getOpenSessions();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection established");

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your java code?

Comment: @psyco - Code added. Please check.

Comment: https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/

Comment: Thanx for the link @psyco. But i want a tutorial kind of thing through which i can setup the server by my own.